# distances between 2d arrays elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> There is given a rectangular bitmap of
>   size n*m. Each pixel of the bitmap is
>   either white or black, but at least
>   one is white. The pixel in i-th line
>   and j-th column is called the pixel
>   (i,j). The distance between two pixels
>   p1=(i1,j1) and p2=(i2,j2) is defined
>   as:

```
d(p1,p2)=|i1-i2|+|j1-j2|.
```

Task

Write a program which:

> reads the description of the bitmap
>   from the standard input, for each
>   pixel, computes the distance to the
>   nearest white pixel, writes the
>   results to the standard output.

Input

> The number of test cases t is in the
>   first line of input, then t test cases
>   follow separated by an empty line. In
>   the first line of each test case there
>   is a pair of integer numbers n, m
>   separated by a single space, 1<=n
>   <=182, 1<=m<=182. In each of the
>   following n lines of the test case
>   exactly one zero-one word of length m,
>   the description of one line of the
>   bitmap, is written. On the j-th
>   position in the line (i+1), 1 <= i <=
>   n, 1 <= j <= m, is '1' if, and only if
>   the pixel (i,j) is white.

```
Output
```

> In the i-th line for each test case,
>   1<=i<=n, there should be written m
>   integers f(i,1),...,f(i,m) separated
>   by single spaces, where f(i,j) is the
>   distance from the pixel (i,j) to the
>   nearest white pixel.

The algorithm I've come up with is :

- read the 2d array, if the element is '1' (white) then save the coordinates of it.
- loop through the 2d array, if element is '0' black then loop through all the white coordinates and find the shortest distance and output it.

Here's my implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct white{
    int i;
    int j;
};

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;

    for (int z = 0; z < N; z++){
        char bitmap[182][182];

        int n,m;
        cin >> n >> m;
        vector<white> whites;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            string s;
            cin >> s;

            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
                bitmap[i][j+1] = s[j];
                if (s[j] == '1'){
                    white x;
                    x.i = i;
                    x.j = j+1;
                    whites.push_back(x);
                }
            }
        }

        int size = whites.size();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++){
                if (bitmap[i][j] == '0'){

                    int distance = 31223123;

                    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){
                        int d = abs(i-whites[x].i) + abs(j-whites[x].j);
                        if (d < distance)
                            distance = d;
                    }

                    cout << distance << ' ';

                } else {
                    cout << '0' << ' ';
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

even though this works it's too slow. Please help me to improve the performance or perhaps this algorithm won't be fast enough ?

Comment: Is this homework? you should use the homework tag if it is.

Comment: @Tom it's not. This is a problem in SPOJ.

Comment: Quick, simple optimization, not sure if it will help a lot: leave out `if (bitmap[i][j] == '0')`. It will be true for almost all pixels anyway.

Also, have you profiled the program? Where does it spend most time? Find this out before trying to optimize unimportant parts of the code.

Comment: Why don't you post the link to the SPOJ page?

Answer (score 4):

You can approach the algorithm from the opposite end, instead of trying to calculate the distance from each black position to all whites, calculate the distances from the white elements to all other nodes. This will allow you to cut many calculations:

- initialize a map with all MAX_VALUE distances
- for each white:

  - set value of map( pos(white) ) to 0
  - apply a recursive function to the positions around white:

    - reduce_distance( left( pos(white) ), 1 ); reduce_distance( up( pos(white) ), 1 )...
    - where reduce_distance( pos, value ) is defined as:

      - if map( pos ) <= value: cut, the recursive algorithm will not improve the existing value.
      - map( pos ) = value: set current best distance
      - recurse: reduce_distance( left( pos ), value+1 ), reduce_distance( up( pos ), value+1) ...

This can reduce the number of operations quite a bit. You can also try to improve the performance heuristically by being smart with the order by which you choose the white points. Imagine the 1D case, if you order the points by the unique coordinate, and you use start with the median of the ordered list of whites, none of the points to the left will require checking beyond the position of that first point, so that you can improve the worst case by choosing the next white point that best partitions the rest of the space.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard problem of image-processing ("Distance Transform") and efficient algorithms exist, refer to
e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform

Answer (score 1):

The key is to think about the distance function you have been given (L1/taxicab norm) in order to perform the most efficient search.

```
d(p1,p2)=|i1-i2|+|j1-j2|.
```

[image]

Around a given pixel, the order in which to perform the search should be

```
    3
   323
  32123
 3210123
3210x0123
 3210123
  32123
   323
    3
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing something similar to David Rodriguez's solution: calculate the distance starting from the white pixels. However, instead of doing a recursive, depth-first search, do it breadth-first, using a queue instead. This guarantees you only need to go through each each pixel once.

```
for each pixel (p):
   cost(p) := +inf

queue := empty queue
for each white pixel (w):
    cost(w) := 0
    push(queue, w)

while queue is not empty:
    p := pop(queue)
    for each neighbour pixel (pn):
        if cost(pn) == +inf:
            cost(pn) = cost(p) + 1
            push(queue, pn)
```